# Python | Payment Calculator [ Computer Science Circles ]

Tags: python

[Image Of the QUestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s741.png)

Hello , Everyone The picture I attached is the image of the question and here is my code :

```
    p1 = balance * 0.021;
p2 = balance * 10;
p3 = max(p1,p2);
if ( balance  <= p3 ) :
    print(p3);
else : 
    print(balance);
```

But It doesn't return the correct result .
any help?

Comment: Change `p2 = balance * 10;` to `p2 = 10`.

Comment: Please don't post to off-site pictures of information relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum payment is the greater of either 10$ of 2.1% of balance & p3 contains maximum value between these two. If this value is greater than balance then balance is the minimum payment so here I use the 'min' function to get the minimum value between p3 & balance

**Code :**

```
balance = 8
p1 = balance * 0.021;
p3 = max(p1,10);
min = min(p3,balance)
print(min);
```

**Output :**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked ! Can you explain this how it works!

Comment: I read the conditions carefully in the question that you have attached as an image and convert in to optimized logic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are multiplying by 10 in `p2`. Also, it might be helpful if you explicitly label your variables to express exactly what kind of data it is holding.

```
def min_payment(balance):
    minimum_pay = 10 . # p in your example above
    payment_by_percentage = balance * 0.021  # p2 in your example above
    if balance > minimum_pay:
        result = max(payment_by_percentage, minimum_pay)
    else:
        result = balance
    print(result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code .

1. You calculate the wrong p2 value ,p2 value is just a 10$ . Not a 10 times of balance.
2. If p3 value is greater than balance value,prints the balance value .Not the p3 value .Because in this case balance value is lesser than minimum payment 'p3' value.

   ```
   p1 = balance * 0.021;
   p2 =  10;
   p3 = max(p1,p2);
   if ( balance  < p3 ) :
       print(balance);
   else : 
       print(p3);
   ```